# chaperone protein names

Tags: protein-folding

I am studying chaperon proteins DnaK, DnaJ etc. This question sounds trivial but I would like to know what the acronym stands for. I have looked on google/google scholar. My best guess is that the name comes from the fact that these are genes whose products are necessary for bacteriophage DNA replication. Can this be confirmed? The full name of GroES and GroEL may also be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DnaK](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P0A6Y8): the recommended name is Chaperone protein DnaK; the alternative names are HSP70, Heat shock 70 kDa protein, and Heat shock protein 70 (source: [UniProtKB](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/)); the name of the protein, DnaK, is derived from the name of the gene, *dnaK* ([Yochem et al., 1978, Mol Gen Genet. 164: 9-14](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/360041)):

> We show that a collection of 93 *E. coli* mutations which map between
>   *thr* and *leu* and which block phage lambda DNA replication define two
>   closely linked cistrons. Work published in the accompanying paper
>   shows that these mutations also affect host DNA replication, so we
>   designate them *dnaJ* and *dnaK*; the gene order is *thr--dnaK--dnaJ--leu*.

To find the recommended and alternative names of [GroS](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P0A6F9) and [GroL](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P0A6F5), search [UniProtKB](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/) . . .